# How to trigger parent element using child?

Tags: c#, wpf

What I am trying to do is when my mouse got over a button inside a border that border background color must change.

```
 <Border Name="HistoryBorder" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Height="30" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Margin="0,0,326.8,0" 
            Background="#FF323030" 
            CornerRadius="0,0,15,0" 
            MouseDown="draging_bar">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Width="75" 
                Name="HistoryButton" 
                Height="30" 
                Margin="0" 
                FontFamily="/Fonts/#Minecraft" 
                Foreground="#FFB6B002" >
            <Button.Content>
                History
            </Button.Content>
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=HistoryButton, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                            </DataTrigger.Setters>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Border>
```

As you can see border is parent and button is a child in it. When I try to use targetname it is not working. Is something like that even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, setting Style for Border to be bind with it's child's IsMouseOver can be one of the ways.

```
<Border Name="HistoryBorder" 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Height="30" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Margin="0,0,326.8,0" 
    CornerRadius="0,0,15,0" 
    >
    <!-- You have to put Background color to Style. Or priority makes it cannot be overrided from the Setter of Style -->
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF323030"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=HistoryButton, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    ...
```